# Template Referencing not happening when origin has a *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-material2, ng-template, angularjs-ng-if

```
<mat-icon
  #suggestionIcon="cdkOverlayOrigin"
  class="suggestionIcon" 
  *ngIf="part.highlight"
  (click)="openOverlay()"
  cdkOverlayOrigin
>
  add_circle
</mat-icon>
<ng-template 
  #myTemplate
  *ngIf="part.highlight"
  cdkConnectedOverlay 
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="suggestionIcon"
> 
 overlay 
</ng-template>
```

I'm getting an error, saying

> Property 'suggestionIcon' does not exist on type 'InteractionPostComponent'.ngtsc(2339)
> interaction-post.component.ts(38, 4): Error occurs in the template of component InteractionPostComponent.

[click on this to see the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WingG.png)

I tried using [style.visible] instead if *ngIf, and it is working, but I want to know why *ngIf is not working

Comment: don't use `ngIf`. use `[cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="part.highlight"` instead

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Template variable scope documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-variable-scope), your `suggestionIcon` template reference is created when `part.highlight` is true. The scope can be explained in the code as below:

```
if (part.highlight) {
  let suggestionIcon = ...; // Create `suggestionIcon` variable within this scope
}

if (part.highlight) {
  // Access `suggestionIcon` is not possible as it does not exist
}
```

Thus, would suggest placing both `<mat-icon>` and `<ng-template>` elements under the root `<ng-template>`, to allow both elements can create and share the template reference variable as it is within the scope.

Also, for `<ng-template>`, you need to use `[ngIf]` (template input variable syntax) but not `*ngIf` expression. Reference: [Angular ng-template, ng-container and ngTemplateOutlet - The Complete Guide To Angular Templates (The ng-template directive and ngIf section)](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-variable-scope)

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="part.highlight">
    
  <mat-icon
    #suggestionIcon="cdkOverlayOrigin"
    class="suggestionIcon" 
    (click)="openOverlay()"
    cdkOverlayOrigin
  >
    add_circle
  </mat-icon>
  <ng-template 
    #myTemplate
    cdkConnectedOverlay 
    [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="suggestionIcon"
  > 
    overlay 
  </ng-template>
    
</ng-template>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-szhqrm?file=src%2Fmain.ts)